# Automapper copy List to List

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-2

I have these classes:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id{ get; set ;}
    public string FirstName{ get; set ;}
    public string LastName{ get; set ;}
}

public class PersonView {
    public int Id{ get; set ;}
    public string FirstName{ get; set ;}
    public string LastName{ get; set ;}
}
```

I defined this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonView>();
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonView, Person>()
    .ForMember(person => person.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

That's work for this:

```
PersonView personView = Mapper.Map<Person, PersonView>(new Person());
```

I'd like to make the same but for `List<Person>` to `List<PersonView>` but I don't find the right syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Once you've created the map (which you've already done, you don't need to repeat for Lists), it's as easy as:

```
List<PersonView> personViews = 
    Mapper.Map<List<Person>, List<PersonView>>(people);
```

You can read more in the [AutoMapper documentation for Lists and Arrays](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html).

Comment: What's interesting to note here, is that the source template can be the most generic type, like `PersonView[]` and the output can be of any other supported type such as `IEnumerable, ICollection, IList, etc`

Answer (score 20):

For AutoMapper 6< it would be:

In StartUp:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Person, PersonView>();
    ...
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
List<PersonView> personViews = Mapper.Map<List<PersonView>>(people);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try like this:

```
var personViews = personsList.Select(x=>x.ToModel<PersonView>());
```

where

```
 public static T ToModel<T>(this Person entity)
 {
      Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);

      if(typeParameterType == typeof(PersonView))
      {
          Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonView>();
          return Mapper.Map<T>(entity);
      }

      return default(T);
 }
```