# Automapper does not work for Lists?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two classes, `Sale` and `SaleDTO`.

When I map objects of these two classes using automapper, it will work.

However, if I do something like this:

```
List<Sale> s = GetSalesFromDatabaseMethod();
List<SaleDTO> sa = Mapping.Map<List<Sale>, List<SaleDTO>>(s);
```

`sa` will turn up empty. Am I doing something wrong?

The `Map` method is basically a shortcut to mapping:

```
public static H Map<T, H>(T i) {
    Mapper.CreateMap<T, H>();
    return Mapper.Map<T, H>(i);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer from 
[Automapper copy List to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899444/automapper-copy-list-to-list).

Apparently the shortcut `Mapping.Map<>()` that I made method would not work, as I need to create the map to the two classes first and then map the lists, like so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Sale, SaleDTO>();
List<SaleDTO> sa = Mapper.Map<List<Sale>, List<SaleDTO>>(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if somebody has the same error as I do.

Here's my way to resolve this:

```
List<Sale> s = GetSalesFromDatabaseMethod();
List<SaleDTO> sa = s.Select(item => (Sale) item).ToList();
```