# How to convert data of IList<Object> to IEnumerable<OtherObject> with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, automapper

Class with `IList<Object>` member:

```
public class RegisterGroupEmployeeRequest : GroupEmployeeBase
{
    public IList<EmployeeBase> Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Class with `IEnumerable<OtherObject>` member:

```
public class RegisterGroupEmployeeCommand
{
    public RegisterGroupEmployeeCommand(Guid groupId, IList<EmployeeCommand> employee)
    {
        Employee = employee;
    }

    public IEnumerable<EmployeeCommand> Employee { get; protected set; }
}
```

Mapper:

```
CreateMap<RegisterGroupEmployeeRequest, RegisterGroupEmployeeCommand>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => new RegisterGroupEmployeeCommand(src.GroupId, src.Employee));
```

How can I convert data of `IList<Object>` to `IEnumerable<OtherObject>` with AutoMapper?
Or is there any another solution for converting this kind issue?

Comment: Do you have the `CreateMap<EmployeeBase, EmployeeCommand>` in your configuration? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I already write that above this code.
```
CreateMap<EmployeeBase, EmployeeCommand>();
CreateMap<RegisterGroupEmployeeRequest, RegisterGroupEmployeeCommand>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => new RegisterGroupEmployeeCommand(src.GroupId, src.Employee)); ///Error 
```
*Error :
```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Xtpo.Security.WebApi.Models.Requests.GroupEmployee.EmployeeBase>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Xtpo.Security.Domain.Commands.GroupEmployee.EmployeeCommand>' [Xtpo.Security.WebApi]
```

Comment: What version of AutoMapper do you use? What is the reason of `Guid groupId` in the constructor of the `RegisterGroupEmployeeCommand` if you do not assign it anywhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automapper copy List to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899444/automapper-copy-list-to-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Remove the `.ConstructUsing()` and leave the entry like below:

```cs
CreateMap<RegisterGroupEmployeeRequest, RegisterGroupEmployeeCommand>();
```

---

1. In this line:

```cs
.ConstructUsing(src => new RegisterGroupEmployeeCommand(src.GroupId, src.Employee));
```

Your Employee is of `IList<EmployeeCommand>` type but you are trying to pass `IList<EmployeeBase>` instead.

2. Since you already have the entry like:

```cs
CreateMap<EmployeeBase, EmployeeCommand>();
```

AutoMapper will handle the conversion from `IList<EmployeeBase>` to `IList<EmployeeCommand>` as well.

3. Passing `Group goupId` seems to be unnecessary as you don't use it in the constructor body.

```
public RegisterGroupEmployeeCommand(Guid groupId, IList<EmployeeCommand> employee)
{
    Employee = employee;
}
```

4. Looking at point 2. and 3. you don't need the `.ConstructUsing(...)` line.