# Transferring objects from data to UI with EF and MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am using EF and MVC. I have a Person table and a Person class which EF populates. I also need to display the contents so my UI (MVC) implementation has a different Person class for its model. It's easy to convert a single instance of one Person to another but what about collections and lists? If I receive several Person entries from the database into my DBSet, what is a good way to convert them into a different collection type?

Or have I got this wrong?

Comment: Automapper. Not sure what else to say.

Comment: use `automapper`, check this link -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899444/automapper-copy-list-to-list

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of it but it looks just right,